# JavaScript html Textarea getting Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea, regex-group

Saw a youtube video that Chrome has Dev-tools and ran it for fun, but it is detecting an issue with the RegEx.exec matches but unsure why.

**Despite the error the function works great in IE and Chrome just as expected**, but I don't want to get ahead of myself before I create more code/pages until this null error is corrected.

This is my first go using javascript to create my own automation webtool running on my computer, where I paste multi-line-text to extract data-matches via Regexp.exec and then perform concatenation for my call-center job.

**from Chrome DevTool**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null           ConcatenateNodeAddr.html:27 

Join_NE_TID @ ConcatenateNodeAddr.html.html:27

onpaste @ ConcatenateNodeAddr.html.html:8

line 27 = var NetworkElementTID = (NodeAddrMatch[1]+NodeAddrMatch[2]+NodeAddrMatch[3]);
```

Confused now why my code "works" for I get the correct-output. I have found similar questions in stackoverflow but it looked like those examples RegEx did not have matches and I must be missing something.

To use my webtool just copy "W  WLBYTYPSH67 WMMM800D  0311.05B  113 " into the text area

I have used regex101 and RegEx group matches good despite the error.

Match1 = WLBYTYPSH67   Match2 = 0311   Match3 = 05B

```js
function ClearForm() {
  document.getElementById("TL1Form").reset();
}

function Join_NE_TID() {

  //  ## Extract NODE and Address to create TID //
  var InputName_NodeAddr = document.getElementsByName('NodeAddr')[0].value;
  var NodeAddrRegexp = /[\s\S]*\s([A-Z]{6}[A-Z0-9]{5})[\s\S]*\s([A-Z0-9]{4,6})(?:\.)([A-Z0-9]{3,5})\s[\s\S]*/;
  var NodeAddrMatch = NodeAddrRegexp.exec(InputName_NodeAddr);
  var NetworkElementTID = (NodeAddrMatch[1] + NodeAddrMatch[2] + NodeAddrMatch[3]);
  alert(NodeAddrMatch[1]); // alert shows the match //
  // ## Output Section  Node and Address ##  //
  var InputName_NodeAddrTID = document.getElementsByName('NodeAddrTID')[0];
  InputName_NodeAddrTID.value = (NetworkElementTID);

}
```

```html
<form id="TL1Form">

  <!–– // ##  Define User Input Section ## // ––>
  <br /><b> Copy/Paste data between into text area<br/> ( W WLBYTYPSH67 WMMM800D 0311.05B 113 )</b><br />
  <textarea name="NodeAddr" rows="3" cols="27" placeholder="W  WLBYTYPSH67 WMMM800D  0311.05B  113" oninput="Join_NE_TID();" onpaste="Join_NE_TID();" /></textarea><br />
  <input type="button" onclick="ClearForm()" value="Reset form"><br /><br />

  <!–– //  ### Define Output Fields for Concatenation ### //––>
  <b>TID:</b> <input type="text" name="NodeAddrTID" size="25" placeholder="WLBYTYPSHAT031105B" /> <br /> The output is correct WLBYTYPSH67031105B
</form>
```

Comment: Where/When do you see an error?

Comment: thank you for quick rely @mplungjan   I only saw it while in chrome dev-tool.  I was expecting error free result since the code appeared to be working fine.

Comment: The code got re-arranged from what I posted.  The form is actually in the top section in the HTML file and after the html </body> is the script.  If you Run code snippet then click "Full page" this will also generate the error on bottom of page, but my "TID" output is correct.

Comment: When the error occurs:  After pasting in the text in textarea field

Answer (score 0):

I been wondering about "document.getElementsByName" being the issue and changed to "document.getElementID" but no change.  From what I found on w3schools, looks like ID method is the preferred now.

It looked like script was running twice upon pasting text and the second iteration was causing the null detected by chrome dev-tool, which could explain why it worked and I never noticed a problem.

I have removed "onpaste" and kept "oninput" which has seem to stop the error within chrome Dev-Tool.  Thought I needed both one for pasting and the other for keyboard input, my bad.

corrected code is.

```
<textarea name="NodeAddr" rows="3" cols="27" placeholder="W  WLBYTYPSH67 WMMM800D  0311.05B  113" oninput="Join_NE_TID();" /></textarea><br/>
```